# Data Table R: Merge selected columns from multiple data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have hundreds of data tables like an example given below that have the exact same of rows and columns.  I would like to merge(not by rbindlist) selected columns (e.g. ID, FDR and LogFC) from all the data tables into an one combined data.table.

```
               ID         P        FDR      LogFC            animals
 1:            A    1.568780e-01 2.5e-01  0.3348365           dog
 2:            B    4.960651e-05 2.6e-04  0.5768812           dog
 3:            C    3.123122e-01 4.2e-01  0.1872491           dog
 4:            D    8.583002e-07 8.3e-06  0.8387016           dog
 5:            E    2.776600e-03 8.4e-03  0.6495237           dog
 6:            F    3.925375e-06 3.3e-05  1.2510581           cat
 7:            G    4.248726e-07 4.7e-06  1.4029001           cat
 8:            H    1.497479e-03 4.8e-03  0.7471876           cat
 9:            I    3.335468e-07 4.0e-06  1.2297170           cat
10:            J    5.889612e-04 2.2e-03  1.0751952           cat
```

I tried using a following (from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39561045/revisions;)

```
DT.comb<-Reduce(function(...) merge.data.table (..., by="ID", all = TRUE), dt.list, allow.cartesian=T)
```

but I am not sure how to pass column selections to merge.data.table. Although I can achieve this by using `rbindlist`, delete unwanted columns (e.g. P and animals) and then dcast the table to convert it to a wide format,  I will be great if I can use `merge.data.table`, or other approach,  if possible.  I'd really appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `by = "ID"` to `by = c("ID", "FDR", "logFC")` and the argument `allow.cartesian` should be inside the `merge`

```
DT.comb <- Reduce(function(...) merge.data.table(...,
   by= c("ID", "FDR", "LogFC"),  all = TRUE,  allow.cartesian=TRUE), dt.list)
```